# MySQL sheduler query

Tags: mysql, events

I need to delete+update in one MySQL sheduler event

queries:

```
DELETE FROM access WHERE d > 0;
UPDATE access SET d = 1 WHERE d = 0;
```

how to combine them in one MySQL event?

Comment: Have you created any event yet? And how frequent you want to event to schedule?

Comment: Check: [14.1.12 CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - First set the `event_scheduler` `ON`.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

> - Now create the event (The event will be scheduled in **5 Minutes**
>     interval)

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `deleteUpdateEvent`;
delimiter $$ 

CREATE EVENT `deleteUpdateEvent` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2016-05-17 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM access WHERE    d > 0;
    UPDATE access SET d = 1 WHERE   d = 0;

END$$ 
delimiter;
```

**Example:**

Suppose you have the following data in your `access` table:

```
id  d
1   66
2   71
3   -6
4   -7
5    0
```

When the event finishes it's execution (**FIRST RUN**) your access table would look like below:

```
id   d
3   -6
4   -7
5    1
```

**After second run:**

**access table:**

```
id   d
3   -6
4   -7
```

**Note:**

For the subsequent runs your table won't change unless you have new data having `>= 0` value

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `myEvent` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS 'yourStartTime' 
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO 
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM access WHERE d > 0;

            UPDATE  access 
            SET     d = 1
            WHERE   d = 0;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```